# HTML to php file

Tags: php

I am coding a simple login form. So first I wrote it as an HTML file and was working fine. I changed this code to a php code on xampp but then the background and text fonts did not appear. Any help please?

```
<body background="C:\Users\hp\Desktop\University\Computer Science\CMPS246\Project\wb.jpg">

<style type="text/css">
    @font-face{
        font-family: BleedingFont;
        src : url("C:/Users/hp/Desktop/University/Computer Science/CMPS246/Project/FONTS/Bleeding_Cowboys/Bleeding_Cowboys.ttf")
    }
    @font-face{
        font-family: NewFont;
        src : url("C:/Users/hp/Desktop/University/Computer Science/CMPS246/Project/FONTS/New Font/JUICERegular.ttf");
    }
    @font-face{
        font-family: NewFont2;
        src: url("C:/Users/hp/Desktop/University/Computer Science/CMPS246/Project/FONTS/New Font2/angltrr.ttf");
```

Comment: Include your code that is having problem. We cannot guess like this, but it could be that you missed to link your stylesheet file

Comment: Show what you have done

Comment: Research relative paths

Comment: Use relative location rather than explicit, inspect code, preferably in chrome, to see if your static files ( css, js, img etc) are being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<body background="Project/wb.jpg">
```

and so on for the other paths, you'll need to provide a path that is accessible to your webserver.